# How do I write a filter that matches SOME of the conditions in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame of basketball box score data.

Like so:

```
 player <- c("Michael Jordan", "Scottie Pippen", "Dennis Rodman", "Tim Duncan")
 team <- c("CHI","CHI","CHI","SAS")
 opponent <- c("SAS","SAS","SAS","CHI")
 date <- c('1999-11-03', '1999-11-03', '1999-11-03', '1999-11-03')
 PTS  <- c(30, 17, 8, 21)
 REB  <- c(6, 11, 14, 21)
 AST  <- c(6, 10, 0, 3)
 STL  <- c(5, 5, 5, 1)
 BLK  <- c(1, 5, 4, 10)
 data <- data.frame(player, team, opponent, date, PTS, REB, AST, STL, BLK)
```

What I wanted to do was to check if a player achieved a 'triple-double', which means accumulating a double digit number in at least three of the five statistical categories. Any three. So I wrote the following function:

```
library(dplyr)        
tripdubcheck <- function(df, count = 10){
      df %>% filter((PTS >= count & AST >= count & REB >= count)|
                   (PTS >= count & AST >= count & BLK >= count)|
                   (PTS >= count & AST >= count & STL >= count)|
                   (PTS >= count & BLK >= count & REB >= count)|
                   (PTS >= count & STL >= count & REB >= count)|
                   (PTS >= count & STL >= count & BLK >= count)|
                   (BLK >= count & AST >= count & REB >= count)|
                   (STL >= count & AST >= count & REB >= count)|
                   (STL >= count & BLK >= count & REB >= count)|
                   (STL >= count & AST >= count & BLK >= count)) %>%
      print()
    }
```

Doesn't look awfully elegant but gets the job done. I added the count argument since most non-NBA basketball is shorter than NBA and triple-doubles are extremely rare so it's more meaningful to use 7 or 8 instead of the 10.

Another interesting statistical feat is called five-by-five, which is when a player gets at least a five in all the five categories.

```
fivebyfivecheck <- function(df, count = 5){
  df %>% filter(PTS >= count & AST >= count & REB >= count & STL >= count & BLK >= count) %>%
    print()
}
```

Now, the obvious limitation going forward is that I'd have to create a new function any time I want to check any other combination. So instead of writing out all combinations of 2 and all combinations of 4, it would be nice to have one function to do it all.

```
statcombcheck <- function(df, count = 10, categories = 3){
   ???????
  }
```

The default there is a triple double and I could change the arguments to get whatever count and the number of combinations I need. My idea is for the function to calculate a count of how many categories meet the count for each row and if it's >= than the categories argument, print those lines.

However this is where my limited R skills come to an end. So any help or a slight nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
statcombcheck = function(df, count, categories){
    df %>% filter(
        rowSums(cbind(PTS, REB, AST, STL, BLK)>=count, na.rm = TRUE)>=categories
    ) %>% 
        print()
}

# triple-double
statcombcheck(data, 10, 3)
#   player team opponent date PTS REB AST STL BLK
# 1 Scottie Pippen  CHI      SAS 1985  17  11  10   5   5
# 2     Tim Duncan  SAS      CHI 1985  21  21   3   1  10

# five-by-five
statcombcheck(data, 5, 5)
#   player team opponent date PTS REB AST STL BLK
# 1 Scottie Pippen  CHI      SAS 1985  17  11  10   5   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Define function where r is the number of points within a category and k is the number of categories.

```
library(data.table)
data<-as.data.table(data)
function_sum_k<-function(x,r,k){
  ifelse(sum(x>=r)>=k,1,0)
}
data[,needed_outcome:=function_sum_k(x=unlist(.SD),r=10,k=3),.SDcols=c("PTS","REB","AST","STL","BLK"),by=1:nrow(data)]
data
           player team opponent date PTS REB AST STL BLK needed_outcome
1: Michael Jordan  CHI      SAS 1985  30   6   6   5   1              0
2: Scottie Pippen  CHI      SAS 1985  17  11  10   5   5              1
3:  Dennis Rodman  CHI      SAS 1985   8  14   0   5   4              0
4:     Tim Duncan  SAS      CHI 1985  21  21   3   1  10              1
```